# Obj-c - Scroll to bottom of tableview when view has loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c

No matter what I do, I cannot get my tableview to scroll to the very bottom when a user gets to my viewcontroller. I'm currently using the following code to try and accomplish this:

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear {

    if (self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height)
    {
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I've also tried pasting this in viewDidLoad, as well as viewWillAppear, and no dice whatsoever. And yes, I am using autolayout. Any ideas?

Comment: What actually happens when you run this code? Does it go into the `if`? Is `offset` a value you would expect? Is the table actually loaded by the time `viewDidAppear` is called? Why not use `UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` once the table is loaded?

Comment: @rmaddy Just realizing the if statement isn't firing...lol that said, if I remove this block of code from the if statement and drop it into viewDidLoad, nothing happens either... How might I go about using scrollToRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too soon. You need to do the scrolling after the table view actually loads. But you've provided no details so it's difficult to give any more specific advice.

Comment: You'd be right, was executing too soon! Posted how I fixed below. @rmaddy